# Is there an Aberration with a Negative Energy Breath Weapon at all in the lore?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dungeons-and-dragons, monsters, lore

Whether it's from D&D (any version) or Pathfinder doesn't really matter, this is lore/flavor intended anyways so I don't need the mechanics.  I just need the name of the creature and where I can find its lore.

Due to my own searching thus far and others below confirming what I've found thus far (that probably the vast majority if not entirety of creatures with breath weapons are Dragons) I am also interested in Aberrations with Negative Energy based abilities at all.

This is primarily for use with the Creating New Races rules for Pathfinder. Between that and some of the content from Bloodforge (from Dreamscarred Press) you can have an "aberration-touched" humanoid with a breath weapon. For this particular flavor I was hoping to gear the creature towards Negative Energy and some ungodly eldritch horror in his heritage.

Comment: Googling `site:http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/aberrations/ "breath weapon" negative` comes up empty for Pathfinder aberrations. Not sure if 3rd party is included, but I don't think 3rd party is valid for lore questions anyway.

Comment: Planescape is a great source for weird and aberrant creatures, and the best place to get answers about Planescape is [afroakuma’s Planar Oddities Question Thread](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?418709-afroakuma-s-Planar-And-Other-Oddities-Questions-Thread-VI). He does sometimes answer such questions here, but you may have more luck seeking him there, or on `#legend` on irc.foonetic.net.

Comment: @KRyan: I tried to provide a response to your suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

Taking MrLemon's suggestion and googling `site:http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/aberrations/ negative` produces 6 results, which after filtering out 'negative level' reduces to 3 aberrations with negative energy abilities, though not necessarily breath weapons.

They are as follows:

1. [Trench Mist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/aberrations/trench-mist?tmpl=%2Fsystem%2Fapp%2Ftemplates%2Fprint%2F)
2. [Havero](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/aberrations/havero?tmpl=%2Fsystem%2Fapp%2Ftemplates%2Fprint%2F)
3. [Drakainia](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/aberrations/drakainia?tmpl=%2Fsystem%2Fapp%2Ftemplates%2Fprint%2F)

Of all of those, the Trench Mist has the strongest link to negative energy, but is also the hardest to work into a bloodline. To be honest, I'm kind of surprised this is listed as an aberration.

Havero's only link is a single attack involving negative energy. But in terms of eldritch horror-ness this might be what you are after. It is basically a collosal writhing mass of tentacles.

While Drakainia is probably the easiest to work into a bloodline as a decent chunk of her abilities are about her impregnating her opponents she has no link with negative energy - in fact completely the opposite; it's the only thing that stops her regeneration from working - and she can also channel positive energy. Which is unfortunate as she even imparted some of her abilities to creatures that are born inside her aura naturally, without them being part of her spawn.

The three aberations that mention negative levels are as follows:

1. [Neh-Thalggu](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/aberrations/neh-thalggu?tmpl=%2Fsystem%2Fapp%2Ftemplates%2Fprint%2F)
2. [Veiled Master](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/aberrations/veiled-master?tmpl=%2Fsystem%2Fapp%2Ftemplates%2Fprint%2F)
3. [Get of Iblis](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/aberrations/get-of-iblis?tmpl=%2Fsystem%2Fapp%2Ftemplates%2Fprint%2F)

The only other Pathfinder centric suggestion I can make is any Undead Aberation. For which you could attach any undead ([Or otherwise Negative Energy linked](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/negative-energy-charged-creature-cr-2)*) template to the aberration of your choice - perhaps even one with a breath attack.

*3rd party

Comment: Note : the (negative energy) after regeneration indicates that wound inflicted with negative energy don't regenerate (as with trolls and fire)

Comment: Ah, so it's actually the complete opposite of a link with negative energy. Oops. Will edit that in. Thank you.

Comment: Note that the Neh-Thalggu have a strong metaplot in the lore of golarion, being heavily focused on during part of  Iron Gods campaign.

Answer (score 3):

Planescape and other AD&D 2e settings had a large number of creatures which "looked like" aberrations, and a few were tied to the negative energy plane. I say "looked like", because they satisfied one or more of the descriptive [features of aberrations](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/aberrations/) in 3e: bizarre anatomy, strange abilities, alien mindset. However when (if ever) these creatures were reprinted in 3e, they were classified as outsiders.

For example, *spectral death* is a being that looks like "boiling clouds of blackness" surrounded by a sickly black-green halo. *Vacuous* (vacuouses, vacuoi?) are undead generated by negative energy spilling into the quasiplane of vacuum - they don't have negative energy abilities, but can suck opponents into their mouths. But perhaps one of the most fitting examples are the *xeg-yi*, which, according to PS Monstrous Compendium Appendix III, look like black octopuses with spherical abdomens and tentacles of negative energy. They were updated as outsiders in 3e (under the more generic name *energon*).

Unfortunately, none of these appear to be good candidates for your purposes. The best try would be xeg-yi as it is not known how they reproduce, but they are also said to be solitary. It is unlikely that they will help generate aberration-touched creatures.

<sub>PS: This answer is partially in response to one of the comments by user KRyan, who mentioned Planescape as a possible source of weird and aberrant creatures. I skimmed through various PS materials for creatures that looked alien and had connections to negative energy.</sub>